# Selenium error -11

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website that uses javascript, and am using selenium for this purpose. I wrote a script and it runs fairly well (if each line is run one after another instead of a whole script) on my local machine, but I absolutely cannot get it to run on a remote linux server. I keep getting the error "WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/app/data/data/junaid/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11".

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_path = 'path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.sitetoscrape.com')
delay = 5
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="bw-group-all"]/div/div/div[3]/section/ul')))
    print('Page is ready')
except TimeoutException:
    print('loading took too much time')
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
ul = soup.find('ul',{'class':'bw-news-list'})
li = ul.find_all('h3')
news_list = []
for l in li:
    news_list.append(l)
with open('news_list.txt','w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(news_list))


driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

I can't find out what this error code means anywhere. Any ideas on how to fix my code?

Comment: What is the chrome and chromedriver version on which you're executing the code on the remote server

Comment: @demouser123 chromedriver version is 2.22. But I guess my issue is not having chrome installed... :(. I'm just unsure how I would go about installing this on a Linux Docker container on a remote server.